# What's the best way to deal with version control system and xcode storyboards?

Tags: ios, xcode, user-interface, version-control, xcode-storyboard

I am pretty new to iOS UI development using xcode and I am struggling on how to deal with storyboards and version control systems.

When dealing with git pull requests I am having a hard time understanding all the changes that are included in that file, even opening the storyboard and moving the "camera" around changes a lot of stuff in it.

So my question is... when drawing a UI with xcode, is storyboard the right tool to do it? i.e. changes made by me (let alone by other developers) are not really human-readable in commits; what is the most savvy way to deal with UI? doing it all in code is feasible?

Comment: I think pure programmatic is better programming across the board, anyway. I don't see any advantage to Interface Builder and most of the serious programmers I know don't use it, if not for anything but version controlling. Not only do I think pure programmatic is feasible, but highly desirable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Storyboards, but in many projects I've been working on, two people never modify a Storyboard at the same time because it creates many conflicts and it's the horrible.

If you use Storyboards and respect this rule It would be a good approach.